# Fixed text for HTML Slider

Tags: html, css

I need a slider that have 3 images and different content on different images..
I need to set same text for e sliders and the text must stay static.. it shouldn't blink.. any ideas?
for the three images i need same content.. But the content must stay there while the slider change

my code is shown below

```
<section class="rev_slider_wrapper">        
  <div id="rev_slider" class="rev_slider"  data-version="5.0">
    <ul>    
    <!-- SLIDE  -->
    <li data-transition="fade">
        <img src="images/banner4.jpg"  alt="" data-bgposition="center center" data-bgfit="cover">   
       <h1 class="tp-caption tp-resizeme text-center" 
                          data-x="center" data-hoffset="10"
                          data-y="120" 

                          data-start="500" 
                          data-splitin="none" 
                          data-splitout="none" 
                          style="z-index: 1;font-family: 'FJord One'; color:#F0E68C;">
                          <span class="small_title">āyuḥ-sattva- balārogya-<br>
                                                    sukha-prīti- vivardhanāḥ<br>
                                                    rasyāḥ snigdhāḥ sthirā hṛdyā<br>
                                                    āhārāḥ sāttvika-priyāḥ </span> <br> 
                       </h1>
                                <!-- LAYER NR. 2 -->
                       <p class="tp-caption tp-resizeme text-center"
                          data-x="center" data-hoffset="15"
                          data-y="450" 
                          " 
                          data-start="800"
                          style="z-index: 9; color:#FF6347; font-size:22px; font-weight:bolder;font-family: 'FJord One';">Foods dear to those in the mode of goodness increase the duration of life,<br/> purify one’s existence and give strength, health, happiness and satisfaction. <br/>Such foods are juicy, fatty, wholesome, and pleasing to the heart.

                        </p>

      </li>

      <li data-transition="fade">
        <img src="images/hom2-banner1.jpg"  alt="" data-bgposition="center center" data-bgfit="cover">  
       <h1 class="tp-caption tp-resizeme text-center" 
                          data-x="center" data-hoffset="10"
                          data-y="130" 

                          data-start="500" 
                          data-splitin="none" 
                          data-splitout="none" 
                          style="z-index: 1;font-family: 'Fjord One'; color:#F0E68C;">
                          <span class="small_title">āyuḥ-sattva- balārogya-<br>
                                                    sukha-prīti- vivardhanāḥ<br>
                                                    rasyāḥ snigdhāḥ sthirā hṛdyā<br>
                                                    āhārāḥ sāttvika-priyāḥ </span> <br> 
                       </h1>
                                <!-- LAYER NR. 2 -->
                        <p class="tp-caption tp-resizeme text-center"
                          data-x="center" data-hoffset="15"
                          data-y="450" 

                          data-start="800"
                          style="z-index: 9; color:#d6c848; font-size:22px; font-weight:bolder;font-family: 'Fjord One';">Foods dear to those in the mode of goodness increase the duration of life,<br/> purify one’s existence and give strength, health, happiness and satisfaction. <br/>Such foods are juicy, fatty, wholesome, and pleasing to the heart.

                        </p>

      </li>


      <li data-transition="fade">
        <img src="images/hom2-banner2.jpg"  alt="" data-bgposition="center center" data-bgfit="cover">  
         <h1 class="tp-caption tp-resizeme text-center" 
                          data-x="center" data-hoffset="10"
                          data-y="120" 

                          data-start="500" 
                          data-splitin="none" 
                          data-splitout="none" 
                          style="z-index: 1;font-family: 'Fjord One';color:#F0E68C;">
                          <span class="small_title">āyuḥ-sattva- balārogya-<br>
                                                    sukha-prīti- vivardhanāḥ<br>
                                                    rasyāḥ snigdhāḥ sthirā hṛdyā<br>
                                                    āhārāḥ sāttvika-priyāḥ </span> <br> 
                       </h1> 
                                <!-- LAYER NR. 2 -->
                        <p class="tp-caption tp-resizeme text-center"
                          data-x="center" data-hoffset="15"
                          data-y="450" 

                          data-start="800"
                          style="z-index: 9; color:#FF6347; font-size:22px; font-weight:bolder;font-family: 'Fjord One';" >Foods dear to those in the mode of goodness increase the duration of life,<br/> purify one’s existence and give strength, health, happiness and satisfaction. <br/>Such foods are juicy, fatty, wholesome, and pleasing to the heart.

                        </p> 
                                <!-- LAYER NR. 2 -->


      </li>
    </ul>               
  </div>
</section>
```

is there any way to set the text unmovable when image changing??

Comment: Can you provide your css and javascript too? And are you trying to create a carrousel?

Comment: js code link   http://jagannath-kitchen.ihostfull.com/Demo7/js/revolution.extension.layeranimation.min.js

Answer (score 0):

you can make another div in this section and make the section position relative and that div position absolute and adjust it by left and top or right the ay you want it

```
.rev_slider_wrapper{position:relative;}
.content-div{position:absolute;top:100px;left:50%;}
```